# Keras: Attention Mechanism For Text Summarization

Tags: python-3.x, keras-2

I'm trying to implement `Attention` mechanism in order to produce abstractive text summarization using `Keras` by taking a lot of help from this [GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4962) thread where there is a lot of informative discussion about the implementation. I'm struggling to understand certain very basic bits of the code and what will I need to modify to successfully get the output. I know that `attention` is the weighted sum of the context vector generated through all hidden states of all the previous timestamps and that is what we are trying to do below.

**Data:**

I got the BBC news dataset consists of news text and the headlines for various categories such as Politics, Entertainment, and Sports.

**Parameters:**

```
n_embeddings = 64
vocab_size = len(voabulary)+1
max_len = 200
rnn_size = 64
```

**Code:**

```
_input = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype='int32')

embedding = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=n_embeddings, input_length=max_len)(_input)
activations = LSTM(rnn_size, return_sequences=True)(embedding)

# compute importance for each step
attention = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(activations) 
attention = Flatten()(attention)
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
attention = RepeatVector(units)(attention)
attention = Permute([2, 1])(attention)

# apply the attention
sent_representation = merge([activations, attention], mode='mul')
sent_representation = Lambda(lambda xin: K.sum(xin, axis=1))(sent_representation)

probabilities = Dense(max_len, activation='softmax')(sent_representation)

model = Model(input=_input, output=probabilities)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[])
print(model.summary())
```

**My Questions:**

- The thread linked is trying to use `Attention` for classification whereas I want to generate a text sequence (summary) so how should I utilize the `sent_probabilites` and decode to generate the summary?
- What is `RepeatVector` used here for? Is it for getting the `activation` and attention probability of each word at timestamp `T`?
- I didn't find much explanation of what `Permute` layer does?
- what is `Lambda(lambda xin: K.sum(xin, axis=1))(sent_representation)` for?
- How does `model.fit()` look like? I have created the padded sequence of fixed length of `X` and `y`.

I would really appreciate any help you could provide. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found tht most research tend to use tensorflow for this task, as it is much more easy to implement seq2seq model using tensorflow than using keras model

This [blog](https://medium.com/hackernoon/build-an-abstractive-text-summarizer-in-94-lines-of-tensorflow-tutorial-6-f0e1b4d88b55) goes into details on how to build a text summarizer in an extremely optimized manner, it explains one dongjun-Lee , one of the most easy efficient and easy implementations

[Code](https://github.com/theamrzaki/text_summurization_abstractive_methods) can be found here, implemented on google colab,

If you liked the idea you can check all of the [blog series](https://github.com/theamrzaki/text_summurization_abstractive_methods#blogs).

Hope this helps